# Implement a moving window (queue) in Java

Tags: java, android, data-structures, queue, accelerometer

I'm playing around with Android's accelerometer sensor, which produces some data at the rate of 100HZ. I need to get a queue of last `X` values, say `X=7` as the figure below shows. Is there a light-weight data structure that I can use for that?

I was trying to use a queue for that, but every time I do `offer`, apparently I also need to do a `poll` as well. So we might need to find a similar data structure that automatically polls.

```
public static LinkedBlockingQueue<Double> accelerationQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(7);
```

Comment: Why is having to call poll as well not a good solution?

Comment: As soon as you box primitives you'll have a performance hit - if performance is key stick to primitives. As you stated the problem is with `BlockingQueue` - if you reach 7 items it will fail to offer any more until a `poll` operation .. so you need to consume values (usually on different threads).  I'm not sure you need a data structure to take a "sampled" amount of data in every 100, simple counters could be used,

Comment: I was told about Apache and Guava's data structure for that. I will use those.